# Database of Galactic Mass?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, galaxies

I'm currently working on a paper investigating any relationship that might exist between the mass of the AGN, or more specifically the relativistic mass at its center, and the mass of the host galaxy. Finding data with estimates of the mass of those relativistic objects is easy, but finding data on the mass of galaxies is quite difficult. I'm wondering if anyone knows of a database which contains information on the mass of galaxies, either their bulges or their entire mass. I realize that mass can be calculated via the orbital curve for the galaxy, however, I can't seem to find databases containing those plots either. Any help you can offer would be of great service!

Comment: Perhaps those who may have this information for their own work don’t make it publicly available.

Comment: @SolarMike, You are probably right about that. In the realm of astrophysics databases, you sometimes get lucky though because many are created by NASA, ESA, etc. so they are public.

Comment: So have you checked Nasa etc? If it is not published then you will be calculating. Then you could post the results...

Answer (score 2):

You don't say anything about what kind of AGN you're looking at, in particular whether these are all in very nearby galaxies, high-redshift galaxies, or some mix of both, so it's rather hard to give a definitive answer.

Basically, published stellar mass estimates (either photometric or spectroscopic) are going to be associated with particular studies, and with particular galaxy catalogs (or subsets thereof).

If you're looking at very nearby ($D < 50$ Mpc, say) galaxies, there's the Spitzer Survey of Stellar Structure in Galaxies ("S4G") of about 2300 nearby galaxies (note: it is missing a lot of elliptical and S0 galaxies), with stellar masses from Spitzer near-IR observations: https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/data/SPITZER/S4G/overview.html

Much larger catalogs based on the Sloan Digital Sky Survey (SDSS) can have stellar masses for hundreds of thousands of galaxies (out to redshifts of 0.5 or so) -- e.g., [Chang et al. 2015](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0067-0049/219/1/8) [there are links in the article for downloading the actual catalogs]. You can find links to other SDSS-based stellar-mass estimates [here](https://www.sdss.org/dr13/spectro/galaxy/).

Stellar mass estimates are also available for various *HST*-based catalogs, so if your set of AGN are from a specific *HST* survey (e.g., COSMOS, CANDELS, etc.), then there might useful sources there.